# string formatting error when trying to multiply tuple elements - python

Tags: python, string, tuples

If

```
>>> (1,2)*2
>>> (1,2,1,2)
```

why isn't this working?

```
'%d %d %d %d' % (1,2)*2

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Is there another way to do this without having to explicitly construct the tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a pair of parentheses:

```
'%d %d %d %d' % ((1,2)*2)
```

In Python, [`%` and `*` have the same precedence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), so your code is equivalent to

```
('%d %d %d %d' % (1,2))*2
```

The reason the two operators have the same precedence is that `%` is also the remainder operator, and thus is considered to be in the same category as multiplication and division.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra pair of parenthesis:

```
>>> '%d %d %d %d' % ((1,2)*2)
'1 2 1 2'
>>>
```

As it currently stands, your code is trying to make the string using `(1,2)` and then multiply that string by 2.